# Exponential Power Fit

Tags: curves, data-analysis

I have 3 data points for a material property (permeability of a gas through an solid elastomer) as a function of temperature.  My goal is to extrapolate the property at a lower temperature.

As a slightly-educated guess, I chose a power fit because many chemical properties and reaction rates have the Arrhenius form: $f(T)=Ce^{-E/kT}$.

So I chose a power fit $f(T)=Ae^{BT}$ (although that's not quite the same as Arrhenius form) and got very good agreement to the 3 existing points, $R^2 = 0.998$, which seems to support that functional form for the dependence.  But then I started wondering if that is saying anything profound, because a power fit could hit 3 data points by necessity.  In the same way as a parabolic equation $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ would fit nearly any 3 points, or a linear equation $f(x)=Ax+B$ would fit any 2 points.

Hence my question, does a power fit $f(x)=Ae^{Bx}$ automatically fit 3 data points well, or is the good fit an indication that it may be a good model for the physics?

Comment: Given two [non-adversarially chosen] data points, you can solve for $A$ and $B$ to fit the two points exactly. So your fit on three points is not entirely meaningless, but there is still a possibility of overfitting. Your choice of model will play a big role given your lack of more data.

Comment: The Arrhenius function is an $S$-shaped curve with temperature. But it's definitely not symmetric about the inflection point, If you are looking at temperatures above the activation temperature, say $E/k$ then you are probably okay with any curve fit. However, at lower temperatures the Arrhenius function grows super-exponentially with temperature. You should have no problem plotting the Arrhenius function and your curve fit to test its validity.